# Converting types in flutter: Map<String,dynamic> to Map<String, double> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I convert `Map<String, dynamic>` To `Map<String, double` in Flutter>? What commands are there?

Comment: Can you include sample data that you've tried so far? also is `Double` or `double`

Comment: I am trying to integrate the pie chart plugin with my backend. A pie chart requires a map data field which is Map<String, double>. while on the other hand, the response I get from the backend by using jsonDecode is in <String, dynamic>. And yes it's double, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`castFrom`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/castFrom.html) method like this:

```dart
final output = Map.castFrom<String, dynamic, String, double>(input);
```

Where `input` is of type `Map<String, dynamic>` and `output` will be of type `Map<String, double>`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of casting I prefer this way to avoid getting runtime error.

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {
    "A": 3,
    "b": "4",
    "c": null,
    "d": 2.4,
  };

  final Map<String, double> result = Map.fromIterables(
    data.keys,
    data.values.map((e) => (double.tryParse(e.toString()) ?? 0.0)),
  );

  print(result); //{A: 3.0, b: 4.0, c: 0.0, d: 2.4}
}
```

More about [`Map`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180360/dart-core/Map-class.html)

Comment: glad to help, you can explore the link for more